# Valor de uma variavel para ser igual á comparação de duas variaveis

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por exemplo como faço para uma variavel ser igual a uma comparação de duas variaveis como neste codigo

```
esquerda = light_x > initial_tx
direita = light_x < initial_tx
baixo = light_y > initial_ty
cima = light_y < initial_ty
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo, igual a uma comparação? não está muito claro o que você deseja, a variável `esquerda` receberá o valor do maior? ou do menor? Faça um `if light_x > initial_tx: esquerda...` tente editar sua perguntar e esclarecer mais o que você deseja

Comment: Poderia ser mais claro em explicar o seu problema pois o próprio código da pergunta jáa responde?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma comparação em Python, seja entre variáveis, ou entre valores diretos, vai ter sempre como resultado um objeto `Bool` - com valor True ou False.

O sinal de `=` simplesmente resove a expressão a direita primeiro, e liga o nome a esquerda ao resultado dauela expressão.

Ou seja, uma linha como `esquerda = light_x > initial_tx`  primeiro faz a comparação `light_x > initial_tx`, que vai resultar em `True`ou `False`, e em seguida, mantém esse valor associado ao nome "esquerda".

Não tem segredo. Na prática, você pode, na sequência, usar a variáel `esquerda` dieto dentro de um `if`, em vez de fazer `if light_x > initial_tx:` você pod usar direto `if esquerda:`.

A sua dúvida  ficou um pouco ambígua, mas espero ter esclarecido o que você queria entender.